# Is it better to use a @Html.dropdrownlistfor or using a select from html and populate it with javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdown, html.dropdownlistfor, razor-pages

I'm working on a Web Application with MVC 5 and C# and I want to know if it's better to use a @Html.DropdownlistFor or a Html select and populate it with JavaScript.

I'm thinking on performance in the application and easiness to maintain the code.

Thanks!

Comment: For readability and cleanliness, use the @Html.DropdownlistFor. You should populate this with Javascript if you want to do clientside manipulation on the data prior to populating.If you want to know about html helpers checkout this blog: https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-built-in-html-helper-classes-in-aspne

Comment: I would have to disagree with @MoneyMurch because a lot of front end developers dislike the server side rendered information from Razor and dislike working with it. So really the answer will be subjective to you.

Comment: If dropdown data was very large then you can use @Html.DropdownListFor using Generic model for fillup that data and if data was very short then you can go with client-side Dropdown. When you populate the dropdown with javascript then it has required each loop for bind dropdown list, so I would suggest you can use the server-side dropdown.